# Once AD Administrative tools are deployed, how do they receive updates? How do I tell what version they are at?

Tags: active-directory

I have some admins who are complaining of certain properties such as "User must change password at next logon" not taking effect. (when they re-open the properties dialog box, the checkbox is missing)

I suspect that this may be related to an incorrect service pack on the AD Tools.

- How do I update the Administrative tools on a pc?
- How do I tell what version I'm running  ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean the remote server administration tools (RSAT) package. Those are updated infrequently - so far there has been an update for Windows 7 SP1 and this specific one [only seems to affect the installer and not any of the accompanying tools](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2011/03/28/rsat-tools-for-windows-7-service-pack-1.aspx). The older toolkit releases have not been updated too often too - the [latest and final release of the Windows Server 2003 Adminpak is dated August, 4th 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16770).

As the RSAT is delivered either as an update package (Windows 7 RSAT is KB958830) in MSU format or as a feature to your server installation, expect it to be updated via Windows Update.

Determining the version seems somewhat of a pain as it is not a regular software package - I could not find any resource indicating that it has a version number in the first place. You might try checking for the version numbers of individual DLLs though (`adprop.dll` / `dsprop.dll` are heavily used by the dsa.mmc snapin ("Active Directory Users and Computers") for example).

The problem you are describing indeed seems to be an [issue with an early (Beta) version of the RSAT package](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/10/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-available-for-windows-7-beta.aspx?PageIndex=2):

> Running ADUC.  Multi Selected 8 Users and tried to turn off the "User Must Change Password At Next Logon" flag and it doesn't have any effect (no error message returned).

Comment: +1 I've seen hotfixes listed for specific consoles, or DLLs leveraged by those consoles, but never for the RSAT suite of tools as a whole and certainly never as part of a .MSU package. The annoying "Backspace breaks the GPO console on 2008 R2" bug has a hotfix, for example, but you need to track it down on TechNet and request the hotfix link.